# Convert for loop to recursive function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion

I've got a for loop, and would like to convert it into a recursive function.

I have a prompt that should pop up for every item and be dismissed before moving on to the next item in the list. This behavior doesn't seem to work with a normal for loop. The loop finishes before the prompt is even displayed, and then only one prompt shows up, even if there is more than one item in the list for which the prompt should have been displayed.

(I'm not totally sure if it will work with a recursive function, but from what I've read it seems promising. If I'm wrong about this there's no point in doing the conversion.)

I've been looking at other examples, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how exactly they work.

Here's my original loop:

```
for(var i = 0;i < items.get_count();i++) {
        var item = items.getItemAtIndex(i);

            //Is the item we're looking at in need of approval?
            if (item.get_item("_ModerationStatus") === 2)
            {
                //Yes, prompt for approval. (code for prompt goes here.)
                //Wait until prompt has received a response before going on next list item. 
            }

            else
            {
                //No, do nothing.
            }
        }
```

My attempt looks a bit sad. I'm not really sure where to go from here:

```
function recursiveCheckRequests(i)
        {
            if (i < items.get_count())
            {
                function checkRequest(items, )
                //???
            }

        }
        recursiveCheckRequests(0);
```

Comment: Your `item.get_item("_ModerationStatus")` may not be an integer itself. Try instead checking `== 2` or `=== "2"`

Comment: The upper block of code works fine. (When I put alert boxes in the `if` statement's handlers, the the boxes show up as expected.) So I don't think that's an issue.

Comment: It seems that the recursive version doesn't solve the issue of the popup prompt not behaving as expected, so I'll have to find an alternate solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the function from inside itself.

```
function recursiveCheckRequests(i) {
    var item = items.getItemAtIndex(i);
    //Is the item we're looking at in need of approval?
    if (item.get_item("_ModerationStatus") === 2) {
        //Yes, prompt for approval. (code for prompt goes here.)
        //Wait until prompt has received a response before going on next list item.
    }
    if (i + 1 < items.get_count()) {
        recursiveCheckRequests(i + 1);
    }
}
recursiveCheckRequests(0);
```

Comment: Ah yes, this works perfectly. It keeps calling itself if there are still items, and exits if there aren't. Recursion is still a bit confusing but it makes sense to me why this works!

Answer (score 0):

this is what i would do

```
   function recursiveCheckRequests(pos,arr,length)
    {
        if (pos === length){
             return true;
         }

            //do something here with the array
         return recursiveCheckRequests(pos+1,length)
   }
    recursiveCheckRequests(0,array,array.length);
```

this way the function is completely independent of the array to be passed and tyou can specify the limit on the iterations to perform.